# Track paid content without authentication on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to offer some **paid** content in the app but I don't want the user to go through an Authentication process. I would like him to enter the app and directly be able to buy some of the content and remember that this user has bought it if he comes back later or *uninstall/reinstall* the app later on. (Like most meditation app on the Store right now)

Is it possible using **Firebase Services** and if so, what would be the good way to track paid content for anonymous user?

Comment: So you want to remember the user without knowing who he is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, like the 'Calm' meditation's app does... We don't need to login in any ways, but we can still buy contents there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Anonymous` user **IS** a user without details (Name, email, password, etc). It has a unique UserID

So **YES**. You can save anything to the database using the `User's` unique ID. But remember. Every app is capable of performing operations inside their sandbox directory. which also has a unique ID and resets when the app is uninstalled.

In a sentece. Firebase won't remember the Anonymous user ID if the app was deleted intentionally.

The docs does state this very well:

> You can use Firebase Authentication to create and use temporary
>   anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase. These temporary
>   anonymous accounts can be used to allow users who haven't yet signed
>   up to your app to work with data protected by security rules. If an
>   anonymous user decides to sign up to your app, y**ou can link their
>   sign-in credentials to the anonymous account so that they can continue
>   to work with their protected data in future sessions.**

Read more: 
[Authenticate with Firebase Anonymously on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account)

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically set it up to where it would redirect the user to a TextField page asking him/her to make a "password" and "PIN" of sorts. This "password" and "PIN" could then be stored into a SQL server database as an anonymous user. When re-downloading the app you could have a page dedicated to purchase recovery where all a user would need to do is input this "password" and "PIN", after they have correctly entered both it would return purchases to their account.

things to be wary of:

-People may use the same password, which is why I recommended a PIN as a way of two-step authentication. Keep in mind also that your app will need to test the password against the server before uploading to make sure that the password doesn't already exist and tells the user that the password cannot be used in such case.
-This is essentially the same thing as an account with a username and password... the only difference is that you aren't going to be collecting other information on them, such as email and birthday, etc., making it more anonymous.
-This is a very rare case of question and I know this is a crappy answer, but honestly this isn't the best idea to implement unless your app heavily relies on it.